# uni-app vue3 script setup could not find the globalData in other vue components

Tags: vue.js, applet, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I use vue3 setup in `uni-app` and I am adding globalData but it does not work in setup sugar:

App.vue

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onLaunch, onShow, onHide } from "@dcloudio/uni-app";
onLaunch(() => {
  console.log("App Launch");
});
onShow(() => {
  console.log("App Show");
});
onHide(() => {
  console.log("App Hide");
});
const globalData = {
  text: 'mytext'
}
</script>
```

I could not get the globalData in my `index.vue`

```js
const app = getApp() as any;
let text = app.globalData.text;
```

However,when I put it out of the `setup` then it works well.

App.vue

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onLaunch, onShow, onHide } from "@dcloudio/uni-app";
onLaunch(() => {
  console.log("App Launch");
});
onShow(() => {
  console.log("App Show");
});
onHide(() => {
  console.log("App Hide");
});

</script>

<script lang="ts">  
    export default {  
        globalData: {  
            text: 'mytext'  
        }
    }  
</script>
```

How to resolve it using `setup`?

Comment: You can't. script setup is a made-up syntax for limited functionality. You'll naturally have problems defining known Vue properties like `name` with it, not to mention custom ones

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks.So,is the last code snippet a correct workaround?I am just curious since I see some articels say that the srcipt setup will export all variables automatically.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. In any corner case  script setup needs to be augmented with script. script setup exposes everything as instance variables (think of it as `data` properties)

Answer (score 0):

From [Vue 3 docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose):

> Components using `<script setup>` are **closed by default** - i.e. the public instance of the component, which is retrieved via template refs or `$parent` chains, will not expose any of the bindings declared inside `<script setup>`.
>
> To explicitly expose properties in a `<script setup>` component, use the `defineExpose` compiler macro:
>
> ```html
> <script setup>
> import { ref } from 'vue'
>
> const a = 1
> const b = ref(2)
>
> defineExpose({
>   a,
>   b
> })
> </script>
> ```
>
> When a parent gets an instance of this component via template refs, the retrieved instance will be of the shape `{ a: number, b: number }` (refs are automatically unwrapped just like on normal instances).

In your case, to expose `globalData`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
⋮
const globalData = {
  text: 'mytext'
}

defineExpose({ globalData })
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-expose-props-from-script-setup?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Thank you.it seems correct in vue3 web but does not work in my uni-app applet,`app.globalData` is empty

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?